# Inverse of a number, c++

Tags: c++

i'm creating a program that displays the inverse of a number using the method:

***Example***:

```
123 ==> 3*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 1*10^1 = 321
```

But the output is always 0. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int a)
{
    int i;
    int x = 1;
    for (i = 1; i = a; i++)
    {
        x = x * 10;
    }
    return x;
}

int inv(int b)
{
    int z = b, j = 0, s = 0, y;

    for (z = b; z = 0; z = z / 10)
    {
        for (y = z; y = 0; y = y / 10)
        {
            j++;
        }
        s = s + (z % 10)*power(j - 1);
    }
    return s;
}


int main()
{
    printf("please enter a number"); int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", inv(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try single stepping the program in a debugger. It should reveal some issues right away.

Comment: And since we are not debuggers (and presumably, neither are you), you may want to consider naming your variables a bit more descriptively. The expression `s = s + (z % 10)*power(j - 1)` makes no sense to me unless I go through the whole function trying to figure out what `s`, `z` and `j` stand for.

Comment: `for (z = b; z = 0; z = z / 10)` that doesn't look right.  Maybe `z  !=  0`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes, OP needs to revisit the chapter on `for`-loops.

Comment: Would it be too lazy to use the std::stringstream to convert the integer to a string, then reverse the string, then convert the string back to an integer?

Comment: @Kay. I use the `std::reverse`, rather than `std::stringstream` to do exactly that.

Comment: I corrected the condition in all for and same result... my idea is to set a counter j that counts the number of digits then using" the last digit*10^(j-1)...

Answer (score 1):

When do you think these two for-loops will continue? 
When do you think they will stop?
*(hint: You are wrong.)*

Watch the values of z and y in a debugger.

```
for (z = b; z = 0; z = z / 10)

for (y = z; y = 0; y = y / 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is set incorrectly.

```
for (z = b; z = 0; z = z / 10)
```

it should be :

```
for (z = b; z == 0; z = z / 10)
```

"z = 0" is an assignment which always returns false. So you never entered your for loop, returning the initial value of "s" which is 0.

Comment: yeah, my bad. Assignation is french. mixing both when programming. bad habit.

Comment: Assignation is English too, but means [something else](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assignation?s=t) ;)

Comment: `z = 0` will evaluate to false.

Comment: What have I drank today... Thanks @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition of a inverse function, no need of any `power` function.Keep your code short & simple

```
int inverse(int b)
{
    int s=0;
    while(b > 0)
    {
        s = s*10 + (b % 10);
        b /= 10;
    }
    return s;
}
```

For your above query ,here is the syntax of a for loop in C :

```
for ( init; condition; increment ) {
   statement(s);
}
```

Comment: I corrected the condition in all for and same result... my idea is to set a counter j that counts the number of digits then using" the last digit*10^(j-1)...

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a `string` and reverse it? This only works of course if you are free to choose your method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int reverse(const int n)
{
    std::string s = std::to_string(n);
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    return std::stoi(s);
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << reverse(number) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```